# Python : Best way to sort a python dictionary based on values ; values are lists

Tags: python, sorting

I have a python dictionary

```
d = {
    "Random" : [1,2,3], "Stupid" :  [1], "Gross" : [1,1,1,1,1], "Ugly" : [2,1,1,1]
    }
```

The above list should be sorted based on the `count` of the list values.

I tried this : `sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)`

But I don't seem to get the right result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean `length`?

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda k: -len(d[k]))
['Gross', 'Ugly', 'Random', 'Stupid']
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]), reverse=True)
['Gross', 'Ugly', 'Random', 'Stupid']
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks, I need to get used to lambda . Sigh
Btw why not use `count` instead of `len ` /.

Comment: count counts the occurences of an item in a list, length returns the number of all items in a list

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi, `[1,1,1,3].count(1)` gives `3`. `len([1,1,1,3])` gives `4`. If you want `3`, use `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting from a dictionary presumably you need to end with one, rather than a list so:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = {
...     "Random" : [1,2,3], "Stupid" :  [1], "Gross" : [1,1,1,1,1], "Ugly" : [2,1,1,1]
...     }
>>> sd = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: -len(t[1])))
>>> sd
OrderedDict([('Gross', [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ('Ugly', [2, 1, 1, 1]), ('Random', [1, 2, 3]), ('Stupid', [1])])
>>>
```